# Discord Bot MessageDeleted event handler not working correctly

Tags: c#, discord.net

I want make a discord bot that logs deleted message.

So I made MessageDeleted event handler but it's not working correctly.

I can't find what's wrong with my code.

[image: Result]

```
private async Task Client_MessageDeleted(Cacheable<IMessage, ulong> arg1, ISocketMessageChannel channel)
{
    Task<IMessage> msg = arg1.GetOrDownloadAsync();
    EmbedBuilder embed = new EmbedBuilder();

    embed.WithColor(40, 200, 150);
    embed.AddField("deleted message", msg.ToString());

    await channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed.Build());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you must await your task. However, you are missing one crucial configuration - enabling the message cache. With Discord.Net and the MessageDeleted event, in order to retrieve the message, you must enable caching since you cannot retrieve a deleted message from the Discord server. To enable caching, please set the `MessageCacheSize` in the `DiscordSocketConfig` object and pass it into `DiscordSocketClient`.

Setting up the cache

```
var config = new DiscordSocketConfig {MessageCacheSize = 100};
var client = new DiscordSocketClient(config);
```

Getting the deleted message from cache

```
private Task OnMessageDeleted(Cacheable<IMessage, ulong> msg, ISocketMessageChannel channel)
{
    Console.WriteLine(msg.HasValue ? 
        msg.Value.Content : 
        "A message was deleted, but its content could not be retrieved from cache.");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

This event is thoroughly documented on the Discord.Net documentation, please see the [MessageDeleted event](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.WebSocket.BaseSocketClient.html#Discord_WebSocket_BaseSocketClient_MessageDeleted).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't developed a Discord Bot before so forgive my ignorance, but I assume this line:

```
Task<IMessage> msg = arg1.GetOrDownloadAsync();
```

Should actually be:

```
IMessage msg = await arg1.GetOrDownloadAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
embed.AddField("deleted message", msg.ToString());
```

with

```
embed.AddField("deleted message", msg.Content);
```

via https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.IMessage.html

Comment: I replaced msg.ToString with msg.Content.

But this time, it's not working.